# error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘sqrt’ based on conversion to type ‘int’

Tags: c++

Сама задача звучит так: Дано число n не более 100 и n натуральных чисел, где n - квадрат натурального числа. Данные вводятся с клавиатуры. Сформировать квадратную матрицу порядка √n.

Вывести матрицу в виде таблицы, следующими строками элементы главной диагонали и побочной диагонали так, как они расположены в матрице.

Вывод выполните по формату: каждый элемент в 5 позиций.

В следующей строке вывести одно число - ответ на задачу.

Постоянно пишет такую ошибку :
****tester**.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
**tester**.cpp:10:19: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘sqrt’ based on conversion to type ‘int’
int m = (sqrt)num;**
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, буду благодарна

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
     int m = (sqrt)num;
    int mas[m][m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){   
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        
        cin>>mas[i][j];
        cout<<setw(5)<<mas[i][j]<<" ";
        
        
    }cout<<endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        
        cin>>mas[i][j];
        if(i == j){
            cout<<setw(5)<<mas[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<setw(5)<<" ";
        
        
    }cout<<endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        
        cin>>mas[i][j];
        if(i-j == m-1){
            cout<<setw(5)<<mas[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<setw(5)<<" ";
        
        
    }cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, чтобы вызвать функцию, нужно воспользоваться  круглыми скобками, но не таким же способом `(sqrt)num`. Попробуйте так: `sqrt(num)`.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте заменить `int m = (sqrt)num;` на `int m = pow(num, 1./2);`

Comment: А почему не `sqrt(num)`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Для конспирации :)